# Issue with bloginfo('stylesheet_url') in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Here is my header.php links.when i enter bloginfo('stylesheet_url') for style.css after running page showing blank sceen.

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dark.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-icons.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Why you are not using enqueue for this ??

Comment: You can use  get_template_directory_uri()

Answer (score 1):

Please try "get_template_directory_uri()" function for get url. Like below

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: i got answer.My code was not working because of this : body:not(.no-transition) #wrapper,
.animsition-overlay {
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
} ,Thanks for help.i removed this from my code now it is fine